# Supporting iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios6, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have project that need to be supported by iOS 6 and iOS 7. The problem is I need to use transparent navigation bar. The question is how can I access frame size for both (for example I need left top corner) it's not a problem in iOS 6, but in iOS 7...

Comment: Just wait one more day until iOS 7 is no longer under an NDA to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

Just create an IBOutlet for for your navigation bar then do a IF statement to check what iOS version the user has, then change the navigation bar properties or do whatever you need to do in code to get the frame size.